# unable to assign index to warm nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch cluster version 7.5.1 with 11 nodes: 3 master+ 2 htpp nodes+ 6 data nodes+ 1 warm node. I have set node.attr.box_type: hot and node.attr.box_type: warm nodes. I am now trying to move the old indices to the warm node. However,facing the following 2 issues

1. As soon as warm node was added to the cluster, shards started to assign on the warm node which should not have happened. Therefore, I have now set the 'cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip' to the warm node IP in order to stop the shards from assigning to warm nodes.
2. When I manually try to assign the old index to warm node, it gives the following exception

```
{
        "type" : "resource_already_exists_exception",
        "reason" : "index [index_name/node_id] already exists",
        "index_uuid" : "KIu4GGyUTEyRuQVR8BmYZQ",
        "index" : "index_name"
      }
```

Can someone help me in achieving the hot-warm architecture

Comment: `shards started to assign on the warm node which should not have happened` that's the correct behavior if you've not set any [shard allocation filtering rules](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html) before starting the node

Comment: In order to stop the shards from assigning to warm which shard allocation filtering rules should be assigned? Should I be updating index.routing.allocation.exclude.box_type": "warm" in elasticsearch.yml file and restart the node? If this filter is applied how will I then assign the old indices to the warm node. Could you please help as I have less knowledge on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to assign all indexes to the hot nodes prior to launching the warm node using [shard allocation filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html) like this:

```
PUT _all/_settings
{
  "index.routing.allocation.require.box_type": "hot"
}
```

When running this command, ES will make sure that all index shards get allocated to hot nodes.

Then you can start your warm node and when it is up and running, you can run the following command on the index you'd like to move to the warm node:

```
PUT warm-index-name/_settings
{
  "index.routing.allocation.require.box_type": "warm",
  "index.number_of_replicas": 0
}
```

When running the above command, ES will relocate all the primary shards of `warm-index-name` to the warm node and remove all replica shards, because you have a single warm node and hence they would stand unassigned.

If you're on ES 7.10 or later, the new way of setting up a hot/warm architecture is by leveraging [data tiers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/data-tiers.html) which simply assigns specific roles to data nodes, such as `data_hot`, `data_warm`, etc, and then uses [data-tier allocation filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/data-tier-shard-filtering.html) in order to route the shards to the proper nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Val. I was able to setup the hot-warm architecture